# Google Calendar fails on hosting server but works on localhost

Tags: google-calendar-api

This has been working just fine. A day a go I started to get the follow without any changes to the code on the production server. It still works on the localhost:

```
using (var stream =
               new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/GoogleCalendar/client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                //string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string credPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");
          
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
               // Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }
```

I get the following error assigning credentials:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Application not found at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs:line 86 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.cs:line 77 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 134 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 60 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at CFRA_MVC.Core.GoogleCalendar..ctor() ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Application not found at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs:line 86 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.cs:line 77 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 134 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\v1_19\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 60<---
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the both json files and folders they were in and it seemed to fix it.